# Transaction failed etherscan, coins disappeared?

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, failed-transaction

Okay, I have no idea what just happened, but I think I just lost like 50% of my coins.
I sent Link from my ledger to binance, and when I checked an hour later, it said failed both on my ledger app and on etherscan.

In this case, the coins should have been reverted, since there is no transaction of my coins anywhere it seems.

As you can see on the screenshot, the balance isn't the same, so I have no idea what just happened.
Here is the transaction history, and the transaction link of the failed one.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x608835629e3260ed94191409d4fd1e17b9d7d34ebd9b4d65ce041cdecfcf42a8

https://etherscan.io/address/0x338f1f7092a9897d1402c57361224dba78e07344

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3xrL.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Your initial transaction to Binance reverted. When a transaction reverts, any state changes (like a transfer of funds) is undone, so your tokens remained on your address. There were however another couple of token transactions for LINK after the failed transaction:

- https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe53061094b5644b416aa079ffb9782eb1cd527f7e8f06e90467fe1328f307bd3, sending 10 LINK to 0x4c1e...86cc.
- https://etherscan.io/tx/0x936b90fcd23f143e04ffbc76c9b74001b009c6f10a38dd7a07f4d9098ef4e413, sending 200 LINK to 0x4c1e...86cc.
- https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9dfe319150c4d696ca6df3a6ea5fa219bc6f9c4708ff325bba6bf0faa615f09c, sending approximately 155 LINK to 0x4c1e...86cc.

If you did not make these transactions, it's possible that your private key was compromised somehow, and you should move all your funds as soon as possible.